# Using derived class members for the initialization of the parent class

Tags: c++, initialization, derived-class, initializer-list

I would like to initialize a class `B` that's derived from class `A`, and where in `B` I construct a cache first that is used with the construction of `A`, e.g.,

```cpp
class B: public A {

public:
  B(): A(cache_), cache_(this->buildCache_())

protected:
  const SomeDataType cache_;

private:
  SomeDataType
  buildCache_() const
  {
    // expensive cache construction
  }

}
```

This is *not* going to work though because the parent object `A` is always initialized first (before `cache_` is filled).

(For the sake of completeness: The `cache_` is used many more times in classes derived from `B`.)

As an alternative, I could do

```cpp
class B: public A {

public:
  B(): A(this->buildCache_())

protected:
  const SomeDataType cache_;

private:
  SomeDataType
  buildCache_()
  {
    // expensive cache construction
    // fill this->cache_ explicitly
    return cache_;
  }

}
```

This has the disadvantage that `buildCache_()` can't be `const`. Also, GCC complains that

```
warning: ‘B::cache_’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
```

Is there a more appropriate solution to this?

Comment: Check out [``boost::base_from_member``](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/base_from_member.html).

Comment: "This has the disadvantage that `buildCache_()` can't be `const`." In your second example it should be `static`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing as-is is undefined behavior, from [class.base.init]/14, emphasis mine:

> Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be called for an object under construction.
>   Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or of a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7). However, if these operations are performed in a *ctor-initializer* (or in a function called directly
>   or indirectly from a *ctor-initializer*) before all the *mem-initializer*s for base classes have completed, **the result
>   of the operation is undefined**.

What you want to do instead is use the [Base-from-Member idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member):

```
class Cache {
protected:
    const SomeDataType cache_;
};

class B : private Cache, public A {
public:
    B() : Cache(), A(cache_)
    { }
};
```

Comment: In C++11, you are allowed to call a constructor from within a constructor, correct? In that case, for base-from-member cases such as this, what is the advantage of a separate class for the member as opposed to simply `B() { buildCache_(); A(cache_); }`?

Comment: @R_Kapp That is incorrect. That code would first call `A`'s default constructor, and then within the body default-construct an object of type `A` named `cache_`.

Comment: Would changing it to `this->A(cache_);` provide better results?

Comment: @R_Kapp No, that's just invalid syntax. It's not possible to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: @R_Kapp: your sample is not a forward constructor, see my answer for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

From C++11, you may use forward constructor:

```
class B: public A
{
public:
  B(): B(B::buildCache_()) {}

private:
  B(SomeDataType&& cache) : A(cache), cache_(std::move(cache)) {}

private:
  static SomeDataType buildCache_()
  {
    // expensive cache construction
  }

protected:
    const SomeDataType cache_;
};
```